# How to disable ASO (Automatic Static Optimisation) in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a Next.js application in which I want to be able to produce a CSP (Content Security Policy) nonce for inline scripts on a per-request basis.

My solution involves creating a nonce within my `middleware.ts` file and setting this on the request headers, where it can be picked up by my custom `Document` component's `getInitialProps`, which receives a context object with properties including `req` (the incoming request).

However, I have found that on some pages there is no request in the `ctx` argument provided to the `Document.getInitialProps` method. The [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering/automatic-static-optimization) states:

> ctx.req will be undefined for pages that are prerendered

Is there a way to disable prerendering in Next.js entirely so that every page is always server-side rendered, thereby reliably gaining access to the request in a custom `Document` component?

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration option available that enables/disables ASO. I guess because it is a fundamental feature of Next.js, and in most cases doesn't make sense to opt the whole application out of this behaviour.

However you can force Next.js to disable ASO for your whole application by using a [custom `App` component](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-app) and setting a "no-op" `getInitialProps` on it.

Note that this comes with the obvious caveat that all pages will need to be rendered on every request and so may impact your UX / load times / etc.

```js
// _app.ts
import App from 'next/app';

export default function CustomApp() {
  // ...
}

CustomApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
  return { ...appProps };
};
```